# Mongo client going over maxPoolSize

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Using the mongodb node driver version 3.6.10, I've set the `poolSize` and `maxPoolSize` to be 6 (not 100% sure which option is the correct one for this version, but both are set).

However, in certain situations - I see `client.topology.s.sessionPool.sessions.length` of 9.

Have I incorrectly configured the connection? If not, in which circumstances would the mongo driver go over the `maxPoolSize`?

Answer (score 0):

poolSize is related to a connectionPool where a sessionPool is fully unrelated and different stuff

Comment: Thanks for the answer so what does poolSize limit? To be clear I'm aware that the client sessions are separate from the server sessions. What I can't see is why you'd need more server sessions that you have connections

Comment: Client sessions are separate with server sessions, but related to each other. PoolSize (ie size of a connection pool) is completely unrelated. Since a connection effectively represents an opened/used socket to send/received data to the server, where a session represents logical information about server "state": https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/server-sessions/